# caching, when running javascript

Tags: javascript, caching

Hi I have the following code which load data from a text file with temperature measurements (The file is generated in a c program). (I think) My problem is then that the side caches the file, so it wont update it to the newest measurement. How can I fix this? It Happens when the sensor has been turned off a while and if the data in file doesn't change for some time.

```
 <script>
    function refreshDivFromFile(){
        $("#div").load("Tempfil.txt");
    }

    window.setInterval(refreshDivFromFile, 1000);
    </script>
```

hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajaxSetup ({ 
    cache: false
});
```

Will prevent all future jQuery AJAX requests from being cached, regardless of which jQuery method you use ($.get, $.ajax, etc.)